# Using IF condition in EXCEL

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

**=IF(ISBLANK(Q3)," ",Q3-O3)** I want to check if a cell is blank or not and then if it is blank, leave it as such and if it isn't, assign the difference..
The problem is, it isn't identifying the blank space in the True Condition,the False condition( Assigning difference) works like a charm.

ANY FIXES anybody?

Comment: A space character (E.G. `" "`) is not a blank or a zero-length string (e.g. `""`). Remove the space from between the quotes or use `TEXT(,)` instead of `""`.

Answer (score 1):

`ISBLANK(A1)` returns `TRUE` only if cell `A1` is *truly blank*. Note that if cell `A1` *evaluates* to blank, (e.g. if cell `A1` contains `= ""`), `ISBLANK(A1)` returns `FALSE`.

`A1=""` returns `TRUE` if the cell is *truly blank* **or** if the cell *evaluates* to blank. I assume this is what you want in this case. Maybe try:

```
=IF(Q3="","",Q3-O3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are saying that Q3 is containing a space?
Why not just IF (ISNUMBER(Q3);Q3-O3;"") ?

Comment: BTW bad habit using spaces. Better use empty strings "" in stead of spaces " ".

Answer (score 0):

> =IFERROR(TRIM(Q3)-TRIM(O3),"")

i.e, if the difference cannot be calulated (casues an error), then leave the result be a null (empty) string.
... and as usual, this cannot be entered in any of the referenced cells (Q3 and O3 here).

*`,` or `;` between parameters - depends on your environment / locale*

Comment: This formula wouldn't work. Blank cells evaluate to 0 when they involve a mathematical operation. The only way this formula would return the "error" condition is if one of the cells contained a string that could not evaluate to a number.

Comment: Forgot about that, adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are attempting to do “math”, you could use if(IsNumber(Q3), Q3-O3, “”). Also, an empty string has NO SPACES, not sure why you’re adding a space in your formula.